# Are there any java Enum of european countries and languages?

Tags: java, enums, internationalization

Is there any java (>5) enum for listing european countries and languages somewhere?
If there aren't any, I'll probably write them from this list : http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/european_languages.htm

But if I could avoid that burden, that would be great!

P.S.: Finally, I'm starting to use the geoNames webservice at geonames.org. For the countries I use this snippet in Groovy :

```
import org.geonames.*

ToponymSearchCriteria sc = new ToponymSearchCriteria()
sc.setContinentCode("eu")
sc.setFeatureCode("PCLI")
def res = WebService.search(sc)
def countries = res.getToponyms().collect{it.countryName}.sort()
```

Comment: why would you want an enumeration of 50 objects? I don't think it will be easy to maintain or to use. Can you detail your reasons for wanting an enum?

Comment: A `Java Enum` in that field would be of **too static** nature.

Comment: Thank you all guys for your insights... I think I'll forget the idea of using an enum for this and will store countries and their languages as domain objects of my app...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is unlikely that professional framework designers will include such an Enum in their library, because the set of countries (and the set of politically-recognised official languages) changes all the time. You’d either have to break backwards-compatibility, making the Enum rather useless for software that is supposed to work for longer than a few years, or you’d have to keep old, no-longer-recognised countries and languages in the Enum.

Comment: I agree that this should not be in a professional framework. I was just wondering if someone, somewhere, has one of those in his own libraries, just to start with...

Comment: you're missing the point: enums are supposed to be forever. countries change.

Comment: Nothing is forever, dude. Can we have an enum of planets in this solar system? According to Joshua Bloch, yes - he has it in his book touted as best advices for Java. According to you guys, noooooo.

Comment: I think the planets in this solar system are vastly less likely to change than the set of politically-recognised countries in Europe.

Comment: I mean from now on. Up until 2006 there was no official definition of planet, [now there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAU_definition_of_planet).

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong to use enum to store some rather stable data. What else can you do, store it in XML? How's that any better? So you don't have to recompile(which is a huuuge hassle)? What year are we living in?

Or store it in database; when a new country is born, we just need to insert a row in the database, and the application, smartly written, will load it and use it immediately - without restarting the applicaiton! Hurray.

Even for Europe, that is such an overkill. I'm sure they don't change countries more frequently than we redeploy our applications, which, in any modern company, happens at least once a week.

Nothing is forever, dude. Can we have an enum of planets in this solar system? According to Joshua Bloch, yes - he has it in his book touted as best advices for Java. According to you guys, noooooo.

Well, at least we could only discover new planets, and we can't destroy old planets (in any foreseeable future), so a planet enum is ok as far as compatability, right?

Tell that to Pluto.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I feel less alone in the world of "not so perfect design decisions that may do the job anyway" :-)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe `Locale.getISOCountries()` and `Locale.getISOLanguages()` will help you.

Comment: java.util.Locale will only give you a dependency on the java framework, and when countries changes you will not get an update until the next java minor release.

Answer (score 1):

At least I'd autogenerate the enum class from that URL. You can parse the HTML, fetch the values and write a java file that defines the enum.

And whenever the content at this URL changes, you can rerun the autogenerator and create a new enum class.

But be aware - every change in the enum has a potential to introduce errors in the rest of the code.